# override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) { movingground.start()

Tags: ios, swift

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {        movingground.start()
```

displays

> method does not override and messages from its superclasses

But if you remove the command the game will not respond to your touches.

Answer (score 0):

So basically I pass code from my game and you will see what are the differences:

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?){
  if let touch = touches.first {

      // detecting touch location
      let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)

      //your code going here
}
```

this method works just fine. Try to use it instead of yours. (I used Swift 2.0)